# Calling to Rest function from attached script returns undefined instead of data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am doing a Rest API in javascript for improving myself and having a little of fun...
And the API works well!

```
const getMethod = function(reqType){
    let req;
    if(!reqType){
        req=server+":"+port;
    }
    else{
        req=`${server}:${port}/${reqType}`;
    }
    fetch(req,{mode:'cors'})
    .then(response=>{
        if(response.ok===true){
            response.json().then(res=>{
                console.log(res);
                return res;
            }).catch(err=>console.error(err));
        } else{
            console.error('Error. Status code: '+ response.status + ' '+ response.statusText);
            return {message: 'Failed'};
        }
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.error(err);
        return {message: 'Failed'}
    });
}
```

I know it can be improved, but for now it works. *console.log(res)* actually shows an Array of Mock Data from Express server.

The thing is that, in order to avoid creating another server, I attached into the HTML the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            console.log(getMethod());
            const res = getMethod();
            console.log(res);
            classifyInfo(res);
            console.log("Get Information");
        }

        const classifyInfo = function(data){
            const ul=document.getElementsByTagName('section')[1].getElementsByTagName('ul');
            let content='';
            if(data['peliculas']&&data['clasificaciones']){
                const movies=data['peliculas'];
                const classes=data['clasificaciones'];
                for(let i=0;i<classes.length;i++){
                    const clasMovies = searchInfo(movies, classes[i].nombre);
                    content+=`<li>${classes[i].nombre} <ul>`;
                    for(let j=0;j<clasMovies;j++){
                        content+=`<li>${clasMovies[j].nombre}</li>`;
                    }
                    content+='</ul></li>';
                }
            }
        }

        const searchInfo = function(data, term){
            const returnElement = data.filter(el=>el['clasificacion']==term);
            return returnElement;
        }
    </script>
```

At *onload* function, res becomes undefined **even if afterwards the console shows the array**. However, I don't know why it is doing this.

I have tried to use *await* for waiting the response, but that does not work either.

Any ideas would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, what I mean is that 
    window.onload = async function(){
        console.log(await getMethod());
        const res = await getMethod();
        console.log(res);
        classifyInfo(res);
        console.log("Get Information");
        }

also returns undefined (even when I get the array data at the console)

Answer (score 0):

Well... It was easier than I thought...

I suppose that I should just surround asynchronous await order with some try/catch just in case...

I modified my API like this:

```
const getMethod = async function(reqType){
    let req;
    if(!reqType){
        req=server+":"+port;
    }
    else{
        req=`${server}:${port}/${reqType}`;
    }
    const response = await fetch(req,{mode:'cors'})

    return response.json();
}
```

Which returns a **Promise** and then I modified the script at my html like this:

```
        window.onload = async function(){
            const res = await getMethod();
            console.log(res);
            classifyInfo(res);
            console.log("Get Information");
        }
```

resolving the promise and getting my good, coming-from-node-server, data.

I like to use *resolve, reject*, but I suppose a try/catch will do the same.